# how to call GAS functions in local html page

Tags: google-apps-script

to demonstrate  what im trying to do using a simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploaderForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/.......exec Method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName"> 
            <input type="text" name="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmail">   
            <input type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

<script>
.
.
.
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onFileUploaded)
                    .uploadFile(content, file.name, folderId);
</script>
```

so this is an example of the html and js page that is in my pc, not in the google app, i just called the google app in the form, and in the javascript part im calling a function called uploadFile, which is located in the google script, but obviously i get an error in the console , it says :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at uploadFiles (6166bff606ac6fee1994e592:67)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

is it possible to call a GAS function inside JS that is not in the GAS html.
is what im trying to do even possible, the whoel reason im doing  this is so that i can pass the username and email automatically from the database to the app, the app works if the html part is hosted in the google app script, but then i cant figure out how to pass the email and username to it because in this case i call the app using ,  so is it possible to pass the username and email through the iframe call, i dunno im very new to this i have so many questions, honestly the documentation wasn't helpful to me. please feel free to comment anything, everythign is helpful

Comment: I've rolled back to revision2. You can copy paste [data from revision3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69560178/revisions) to your new question. See [ask]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39e81ba5-7d27-4c4a-a388-cca2d7b9f701/view-source

Comment: yes thank you, i created a new topic here, would you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567419/how-to-pass-username-to-gas-from-local-webpage

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just `post`ing the form data, you can name the function you want to call as [`doPost()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)(instead of `uploadFile`) and it will receive the posted data. You have to republish the webapp as a new version after the modification.

Comment: problem is in the javascript  this function google.script.run.withSuccessHandle ,is  used to call two functions that exist in the GAS, one functioned named uploadfile, and one named create folder ,  create folder is called when all files are uploaded, so even if i change the function uploadfiles to a doPost function, ill still need a way to reach the createfolder function

Comment: @abderrahmanemya Call `createFolder()`  inside `doPost()` or put both inside: `function doPost(e){uploadFiles(e);createFolder(e)}`

Comment: @abderrahmanemya You're free to comment here

Comment: ill provide the full code, ill edit the topic and then you can  see if  this can be done, this is good

Comment: @abderrahmanemya Editing questions to change the original is frowned upon. Better to ask a new question instead.

Comment: ok im sorry it felt wrong you're right

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it as a dialog. I returned the data back into the success handler and loaded by into the html to insure it was working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <body>
    <form>
            <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName"/> 
            <input type="text" name="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmail"/>   
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadfile(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <div id="msg"></div>
<script>
  function uploadfile(form) {
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler((m) => document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = m)
    .uploadMyFile(form);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
function uploadMyFile(obj) {
  return `Applicant Name: ${obj.applicantName}<br />Applicant Email: ${obj.applicantEmail}`;
}

function launchFormDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2'),'Test Dialog');
}
```

Dialog:

[image]